# Monit process failed to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monit

I'm trying to use Monit to watch a Thin Rails application server process.  Here is my Monit config:

```
check process thin-3000
  with pidfile /var/www/apps/myapp/shared/pids/thin.3000.pid
  start program = "/bin/su - deploy -c 'thin start -C /etc/thin/myapp.yml -o 3000'"
  stop program = "/bin/su - deploy -c 'thin stop -C /etc/thin/myapp.yml -o 3000'"
  if failed port 3000 then restart
  group thin
```

**This actually works.**  If I kill the Thin server process, Monit will faithfully restart it.  However, if I watch the Monit log it keeps outputting the following over and over again:

```
[UTC Jan 14 23:01:04] error    : 'thin-3000' process is not running
[UTC Jan 14 23:01:04] info     : 'thin-3000' trying to restart
[UTC Jan 14 23:01:04] info     : 'thin-3000' start: /bin/su
[UTC Jan 14 23:01:34] error    : 'thin-3000' failed to start
```

It looks like whatever mechanism it's using to check if the process is running isn't working correctly.  Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work without `if failed port 3000 then restart` ?

Comment: Yeah, the problem still occurs if I pull that line out.

Comment: `if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3000 then restart` could you check the config. Or `if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3000 protocol http then restart `

Comment: I had tried the first one with no luck.  Just tried the second one, but that also ended up with the same results.  Thank you for trying to take a stab at this, though.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Who owns the pidfile? Can the process running monit access it?